# indefinite article in a New York Times article

Tags: grammar, indefinite-article

This is an excerpt from [a New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/live/2022/01/11/us/biden-harris-voting-rights).

> One prominent family attended the event. Martin Luther King III, the
> oldest living son of the civil rights leader, and his wife, Arndrea
> Waters King, **met privately** with Mr. Biden in Atlanta before the
> president and the King family, who have planned a series of marches to
> pressure Democrats to pass the legislation, visited the civil rights
> leader’s crypt.
>
> During **a** private meeting with the president, the Kings said in an
> interview, they did most of the talking.

I think the indefinite article in bold should be changed into 'the' because their private meeting is already mentioned above.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, logically it should - presumably the journalist made a slip.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I suppose one night argue that to represent their quote faithfully, one can't presume that the meeting they referred to in the interview is the same as the one already mentioned, even if it's extremely likely.

Comment: Thank you very much.